# Moving from pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core

I have this very long preamble and I'm struggling to switch to XeLaTeX. I'm working with PdfLaTeX, but since I want to change some fonts, I would like to switch to XeLaTeX. 
I tried to load polyglossia instead of Babel, but then it says that XeLaTex did not succeed. 
I post my preamble and my log.
Thank you to all.
NC

== PREAMBLE == (don't look at comments)

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,titlepage]{article}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{german}


\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xpatch,amsmath,systeme,mathtools}
\let\xleftrightarrow\undefined
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} % same font as thm-header
\xpatchcmd{\@def}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} % same font as thm-header

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 9999{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\longleftrightarrowfill@{%
\arrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\spn}{Span} %definisco operatore span con \spn per la parte generatrice di una fam. di vettori.
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} % definisco operatore tr con \tr per la traccia di una matrice.
\DeclareMathOperator{\rg}{rang} %definisco operatore rang con \rg per il rango di una matrice.

\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\openbox\relax
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulsy}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,matrix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}


\sectionfont{\Huge}


\author{Niccolò Cavallini}
\title{Elementi di Algebra lineare}
\date{}

\textwidth16cm
\textheight23cm
\topmargin0mm
\headheight15mm
\headsep10mm
\oddsidemargin0mm
\evensidemargin0mm
\parindent0mm




% DIMOSTRAZIONE - STRUTTURA
%   fbox{
%       \parbox{0.97\textwidth}{
%                            \begin{center}
%                                        DIMOSTRAZIONE PER #1
%                             \end{center}  
%                        #2 \ \ \ \ $\blacksquare$
%  }
%}
%dove #1 è il METODO e #2 è il TESTO della dim.

\renewcommand{\emptyset} {\varnothing}
\newcommand {\vecl}{\overrightarrow}






\begin{document}
```

== LOG ==
See here: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxnaahpzo4i3y3r/log_xelatex.txt?dl=0) (this exceeded characters limit)

Comment: It doesn't look like you have to typeset complex scripts (Arabic, Japanese, etc) so better use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX.

Comment: You don't need polyglossia for German and Italian.  Babel will work fine. But you will have to clean up your preamble.

Comment: Other than the non-standard package `ulsy`, if I add some text, your file compiles: please try to cut down your issue to a minimal example.

Comment: if you post code please always post a complete small document that shows the issue not fragments that we can not run, for luatex or xetex remove the 8bit font packages so delete `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and  `\usepackage{newtxtext} `

Comment: Instead of setting the page dimensions directly, it is advised to use the `geometry` package and its facilities (which you already do, but then override it setting the respective dimen yourself).